# Display corresponding table row on button click in another table in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is the Jquery code I have written to show the corresponding table row on the corresponding button click and hide the other rows

As it stands , I am not able to display the row with this code , I would like your guidance on what I am doing wrong. Thank you

I apologize for the long and detailed question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Item_1,#Item_2,#Item_3,#Item_4,#Item_5,#Item_6,#Item_7,#Item_8,#Item_9,#Item_10,#Item_11,#Item_12").click(function(event){
    alert("enter on click event");
event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var fil = new Array();
var rows = $("table.increaseItem tr");
rows.each(function(i){
    fil[i] = $(this).attr('class');
});
    var len = fil.length();
  alert("the id of the button is"+ id);
  alert("the class of the row is"+fil);
  alert("the length of fil is"+ len);

 for (var j=0; j<= len; j++){

     if (id==fil[j]) {

        rows.filter('.'+fil[j]).show();

     }

     else {

      rows.not('.'+fil[j]).hide();
     }



 }

 });

 });
```

Below is the HTML for the table of buttons and the rows I want to display on the button click

```
<table id="Buttons">
<tr>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_1" class="Item_Selection">Item 1</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_2" class="Item_Selection">Item 2</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_3" class="Item_Selection">Item 3</button></td>
 <td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_4" class="Item_Selection">Item 4</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_5" class="Item_Selection">Item 5</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_6" class="Item_Selection">Item 6</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_7" class="Item_Selection">Item 7</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_8" class="Item_Selection">Item 8</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_9" class="Item_Selection">Item 9</button></td>
<td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_10" class="Item_Selection">Item 10</button></td>
  <td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_11" class="Item_Selection">Item 11</button></td>
  <td class="Item_options"><button id="Item_12" class="Item_Selection">Item 12</button></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```
<div id="IncreaseDecreaseTable">
<table id="DisplayRowsbyButton" class="increaseItem">
<tr class="Item_1">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>

</tr>
 <tr class="Item_2">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_3">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_4">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_5">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_6">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_7">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_8">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_9">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_10">
<td><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_11">
<td ><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="Item_12">
<td ><input type="text" id="CountIncrease" class="IncreaseCount"></input> </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td ><button id="Increase">+</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td ><button id="Decrease">-</button></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><input id="Total"></input></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<td><button id="AddButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
<td><button id="RemoveButton">Delete from Cart</button></td>
</t>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. If you can create a simplified executable example (jsfiddle, SO snippet), and explain in details what exactly is "corresponding row", it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear . I have two tables. Table 1 has buttons , Table 2 has rows that need to be displayed on button click. I want to Row 1 of Table 2 to display when I click Button 1 of Table 1. The rest of the rows should be hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Item_1,#Item_2,#Item_3,#Item_4,#Item_5,#Item_6,#Item_7,#Item_8,#Item_9,#Item_10,#Item_11,#Item_12").click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#DisplayRowsbyButton .' + id).show();
    });
});
```

Change your whole js section to this

also add style="display:none;"  with all second table tr

If you want hide all other tr on second , show only coresponding to clicked button, use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Item_1,#Item_2,#Item_3,#Item_4,#Item_5,#Item_6,#Item_7,#Item_8,#Item_9,#Item_10,#Item_11,#Item_12").click(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#DisplayRowsbyButton tr').hide();
        $('#DisplayRowsbyButton .' + id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: comment if you need some modification

Comment: Hi Mujeebu , worked like a charm.. Thanks man. I tried everything , didn't think it would be this simple. Thank you!